# How to count the same where method in Laravel 5.4 notifications to get the 2 notification types?

Tags: laravel, notifications

I'm trying to count two notification types, where i get notified when a user donates and when a user cancels it. how should I do it?

I have this and this returns 0 count:

```
{{ count(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications->where('type','App\Notifications\NewDonation')->where('type','App\Notifications\CancelDonation')) }}
```

Comment: count them separately and eventually add, if you need sum...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
auth()->user()
    ->unreadNotifications
    ->whereIn('notifiable_type', [
        'App\Notifications\NewDonation', 
        'App\Notifications\CancelDonation',
    ])
    ->count()
```

I think you've defined the `type` column incorrectly. by default, it's `notifiable_type`, not `type`

Also, in your original code snipper, you do `->where()->where()`.

Each time you call `->where()`, it'll return a new collection. So the first `where()` will return all notifications where the type is the `NewDonation` type.

When you call `where` again for `CancelDonation`, the only records your collection will contain will be `NewDonation` notifications. therefore, after the second `where, it wont have any records found.